# Multiple UICollectionViewCell color gets changed together issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have created a `UICollectionView` with 12 cells in it.  I would like to have their color changed (to the same color) on tap.

Here is my code :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)as! InterestCollectionViewCell
    print("2 \(cell.interest)  \(indexPath.row)")

    if  cell.selected == true {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
    else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }
}
```

**Issues**

1. Color doesn't change back when tapped again
2. When I tap on the [0] cell, the [5] and [10] cells changes color as well. Same after I tap on the [1] cell, [6]and [11] cells get called too...etc.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting color in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` set the color in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` for that you need to declare instance of `Int` and store the row of `collectionView` inside that instance like this.

```
var selectedRow: Int = -1

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)->UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CELL", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! InterestCollectionViewCell
    // Set others detail of cell
    if self.selectedRow == indexPath.item {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
    else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }
    return cell
}
```

Now in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` set the `selectedRow` reload the `collectionView`.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if self.selectedRow == indexPath.item {
        self.selectedRow = -1
    }
    else {
        self.selectedRow = indexPath.item
    }
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

**Edit:** For multiple cell selection create one array of `indexPath` and store the object of indexPath like this.

```
var selectedIndexPaths = [NSIndexPath]()

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)->UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CELL", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! InterestCollectionViewCell
    // Set others detail of cell
    if self.selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
    else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }
    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if self.selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
        let index = self.selectedIndexPaths.indexOf(indexPath)
        self.selectedIndexPaths.removeAtIndex(index)
    }
    else {
        self.selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
    }
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Hi Nirav, thanks for your answer. It fixes the issues where more than one cell gets called and colors can change back. However, do you know the approach to enable multiple selection so that users can tap on more than one item?

Comment: @WoShiNiBaBa Check the edited answer for multiple select :)